# No more SVG stacking technique, what now?

Tags: css, svg

I have a lot of css looking like this:

```
.T {
background-size: 1.8rem, auto;    
background-image: url('./Images/ListIcons.svg#T');
padding-left: 1.8rem;
}
```

Where ListIcons.svg is a stacking of images (amongst which one "is" T).
I can then use such class on text containing node like:

```
<label class="T">some text</label>
```

which renders like:

```
<T image>some text
```

It doesn't work in Chrome anymore, and will stop working in other browser soon (standard gurus had to fix a issue with SVG/CSS*).

I hear one should just go back to the good* old sprite maps technique.
As far as I know, there's no way to clip a background image to the portion wanted, let alone while using background-size.

Is there a workaround?

- http://robert.ocallahan.org/2012/10/impending-doom-for-svg-stacks-sort-of.html
- not good imho

**EDIT:**
I figured out I could somehow hide portions of the backgroud instead of clipping it.

It goes like this:

```
.ButtonType {
    background-size: 0.1rem 100%, 100% 100%, auto 1.8rem;
    background-position: left center, 1.9rem center, calc(-6 * 1.8rem + 0.1rem) center;
    background-image: url('./Images/White.png'), url('./Images/White.png'), url('./Images/ListIcons.svg');
}
```

(6th image with a size of 1.8/1.8 rem padded 0.1rem from left + concealment of "non 6th image" using white images).

It's long, color dependent (wherever background is another color, one have to rewrite the almost exact same two line), and has to be repeated for every single use of the sprite map as a background.

Simply put: it sucks (yet it works).

I feel like going back to 1 image = 1 file, and not trying to reduces # files accesses.